# How to set CHROME_BIN in jenkins when deploying to production for angular test coverage

Tags: jenkins, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have a maven project that I deployed to a jenkins server, and I would like to run code coverage report there for my AngularJS code. I have jenkins installed a service on my local machine, and have my tests running there when I build my project.

The tests are passing fine, but when I try to build on my production server, the build fails when trying to run my tests, and throws this error here ( I just did a copy pest of the error)

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.0:grunt (grunt-karma) @ forecast-guardian-4 ---
[INFO] Running 'grunt ' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TaskName
[INFO] Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
ERROR [launcher]: [39mNo binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
[INFO]   Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [33mWarning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.[39m
[INFO] 
[INFO] [31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
[INFO]
```

My research on that shows how to set that variable if you are on the local machine, which I didn't have to do by the way. I was wondering if anyone can help me configure this.

How can I set this variable to produce something like what find [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/docs/config/03-browsers.md#correct-path-to-browser-binary) for setting it on local machine?

**More info**: As that error shows, my project uses `grunt` to run the test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) or put `export CHROME_BIN=/your/path/here` into .bash_profile and run `source ~/.bash_profile` at the beginning of your job.

Comment: I have that already installed. But I don't understand how I can give the path to the chrome bin. I have installed [ChromeDirver](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ChromeDriver+plugin) thinking that that will fix it but no. On the local machine you can use the path like `CHROME_BIN=/usr/local/bin/my-chrome-build`, but I don't know how I can reproduce that on jenkins server.

Comment: There is a section in [this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin#EnvInjectPlugin-Configuration) called `At Job Level` > `Inject variables after a SCM checkout`. Just put `CHROME_BIN=/usr/local/bin/my-chrome-build` into `Properties Content` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried that but with various versions of the path, but no luck. I think I might be missing something, but I don't know what. I am continuing testing with various paths set to CHROME_BIN variable, and see if I get a hang of it and move on.

Comment: Is there something actually in that location? Did you install it somewhere else? Also, you could put a step in your job that echos `CHROME_BIN` to confirm that it's being set. If it's being set, your path is probably wrong.

Comment: I thought that too, that's why I was giving different paths. CHROME_BIN is being set properly, and the `echo` is showing the path I gave to it. The reason why I used different paths is because on my local jnkins service, the job is being run from `c://path/to/my/.jenkins/workspace/JobName`, and on the Jenkins serve I want to publish the tests, it is run from `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JobName`, and ended up setting `CHROME_BIN=**/chorme-browser` so that it can in the whole project (if I am not mistaken). So maybe I am giving the wrong bin name.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like you're misinterpreting `CHROME_BIN`. That is used to specify where the Chrome binary lives on your Jenkins server. So, first you need to have Chrome installed, then you need to set the env variable `CHROME_BIN` to that binary. After that, Karma should be able to use that env var to call Chrome. From your last comment, you are setting `CHROME_BIN` to the directory of your Jenkins job, which won't do you any good, unless you have a Chrome binary in your Jenkins build job for some reason.

Comment: Yes, `CHROME_BIN` is where chrome binary lives. I searched install chrome on Jenkins, and the most relevant answer was to install [ChromeDriver](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ChromeDriver+plugin) which I have installed, and its documentation says that there is no configuration required. Unless there is some other sort of Chrome out there I am missing, that's all I have. Also, the path I provided is not what I am using, that was to show the difference of where the jobs are located where running on Jenkins service and Jenkins server.

Comment: I believe that's your problem. ChromeDriver is a web driver used for Selenium testing. From what I'm reading, you need to have the Chrome browser installed on the Linux machine that you're using for the Jenkins server. From the very first line of the Karma GitHub repo: `A simple tool that allows you to execute JavaScript code in multiple real browsers.`. That means you need to have a browser installed on the system, just like you need the browser installed on your local Windows system.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't think beyond my lack of testing experience! ;-b I am going to retract my focus and change my search engine key words.

Comment: Feel free to come back and accept this answer, should the EnvInject plugin work for you once you install Chrome. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141996/discussion-between-mupierrix-and-jacob).

Comment: It turns out that the server used ti host our jenkins is a linux server and doesn't have a UI to install the browser on, so I changed and use `PhantomJS` instead, thanks to this post [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2013)

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to solve this was to have my CI system run the `karma` commands inside one of [the pre-built Puppeteer docker images](https://pptr.dev/guides/docker).

e.g. in my CI yaml config file I put:

```yaml
image: ghcr.io/puppeteer/puppeteer:19.4.1
```

I found this version is [the latest Dockerfile that uses Node v16](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/puppeteer-v19.4.1/docker/Dockerfile) to match our projects version.

Answer (score 0):

The docker run command accepts env file by the `-env-file` flag.

So, you can add a new env file with the following

```
CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

and pass this file to docker run command

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list -t -d ${BUILD_NAME}
```

refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) for the official docs

This way, we don't puppeteer just to set the env variable.